# how to redirect php file in apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I have the following link.   elad.test.com/test.php
I would like to be able to typ  elad.test.com and get to that URL.
I know I have to do it with .htaccess but it doesn't work for me.

can someone please assist?

Comment: You can post your .htaccess content here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Htaccess redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501732/htaccess-redirect)

Answer (score 2):

if you do not want to use the .htaccess file, you can always use and index.php file that redirects to the test.php using

```
header("location: test.php");
```

Alternatively, if you want your browser to redirect to test.php instead of index.php when you request a directory (ie elad.test.com/ - which is the index directory of the server), you can do from by changing the apache configuration. Note that this will affect every directory in the server.

Comment: Careful: headers should be capitalized and location should always be absolute URI. For example: `Location: http://www.example.com/test.php`.

Comment: to be honest, on every site I worked on I rarely used absolute URIs and it kept working. in any case, the manual says so, so it's true :)

Comment: Most browsers will respect relative URIs, but they still violate [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.30). It is best to be extra careful when generating stuff (your server) and forgiving when accepting it (browser).

Comment: I do want to use .htaccess. I"m using more than 1 virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `test.php` to be the first load order for the `test` subdomain:

```
DirectoryIndex test.php index.php index.html index.htm default.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a index.php (or whatever your default file is called) file and use it to redirect to your test.php file.

Sample:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://elad.test.com/test.php');
exit;
?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're only hosting 1 virtual host, you can omit the RewriteCond. In your .htaccess file add in an appropriate place:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^elad\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /test.php [L]
```

This will make it so if you type http://elad.test.com/ in your location bar in your browser, you'll get the /test.php page (but your browser's location bar won't change).

Comment: I do want to use .htaccess. I"m using more than 1 virtual host

Comment: Is this rewrite rule not working for you then? Add it to your .htaccess file.