# htaccess redirect a new address with anchor

Tags: .htaccess

I need at the opening a address,

```
   http://mysite.com/page.php
```

happened redirected to this address:

```
   http://mysite.com/other_page.php#!blablabla
```

tell please, how to make this with .htaccess file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for example, will be converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE] flag prevents that from happening.

```
RewriteRule ^/anchor/(.+) /bigpage.html#$1 [NE,R]
```

The above example will redirect /anchor/xyz to /bigpage.html#xyz. Omitting the [NE] will result in the # being converted to its hexcode equivalent, %23, which will then result in a 404 Not Found error condition.

see also this question:

[Htaccess redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501732/htaccess-redirect)